# Solidity random number security using keccak256 when contract caller is known

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-number-generator-in-solidity-using-keccak256/) about the standard way to generate random numbers in solidity using keccak256 and timestamp, contract caller and nonce as a source of entropy.

I also read in the article linked above that the main problem with this method is that when the caller of the contract also has his own node, he can publish infinite transactions to his own node, but not share them, until he generated the number he wants.

My question is, in case that my smart contract is meant to be called just from the trusted source, is then this method of generating random numbers safe?

I am also wondering if I generate a new Ethereum address each time to call the contract, does that add to the entropy, and make the number impossible to predict?

It seems to me that generating new address each time adds enough entropy and in a way the source that generates the addresses and calls the contract plays a role of an oracle. Is that right?

Comment: The linked article is very, very, bad example and exactly what should not be done in cryptography

Comment: the Miner of the block can see your random number , and re-execute the transaction with that number, taking all the rewards of the transaction

Answer (score 0):

Any random number generated in a smart contract can be guessed beforehand by someone. Thus any random number generated in a smart contract is insecure.

If you call the smart contract from the trusted source, you can as well generate the random number in the trusted source and not be kicking the can down the road. Generating addresses is just smoke and mirrors as of course, someone knows what addresses they are generating.